# Html Audio Element Source - How to use an API call to get sound bytes

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have this Audio element which will play a 5 second sound clip. (It's a language learning site.  The user will record a short clip of a word in a second language, and then later he can play it back.)

This works as a file on desk:

`<audio src="./audio/Clip1.webm" controls></audio>`

But what I really want to do is store the sound byte in a database and then feed it to the player like this:

`<audio src="api/audio/Clip1" controls></audio>`

But I am not sure of what needs to be returned form the API call in order for the Audio element to play it.  Should it be returning it as a file?  The data is not stored as a file, so if this is the case, then I would have to somehow create the response to be in the form of a file.

Or is there a better way to feed it the bytes (of cheese maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working:

```
<audio controls src="data: audio/wav;base64, (Convert.ToBase64String(item.AudioBytes))"></audio>
```

Found this solution [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery) on MDN